# SQLAlchemy default filter

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a model with a field is_deleted, now I want all forms of query for this model to always  filter by is_deleted=False in addition to whatever filtering arguments is passed to .filter and .filter_by.

In Django, I would normally override the manager and add my own filtering but I need help for SQLAlchemy.

**UPDATE:**

I ended-up doing the following:

```
class CustomQuery(Query):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if args and hasattr(args[0][0], "is_deleted"):
            return Query(*args, **kwargs).filter_by(is_deleted=False)
        else:
            return object.__new__(cls)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(query_cls=CustomQuery))
```

It works but if I have more fields later on I imagine I'll have to add more condition, there must be a way to do this on the model level.

Comment: We have exactly this recipe here at https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/FilteredQuery

Comment: what do you mean exactly "the model level" ?   can you illustrate an example of how you'd like it to look ?

Comment: @zzzeek, I think he meant hacking the table, and not the query.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very old question so I'm sure the OP solved their issue, but as it remains unanswered (in 2021) here's how we've approached applying a custom query class to all models:

1. Define the custom query as above

```py
class CustomQuery(Query): ...
```

2. Then set this query class as the query attribute on your base model class:

```py
class BaseModel(Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    query_class = CustomQuery
    ...
```

Then any models implementing the BaseModel will obviously inherit this behaviour:

```
class MyModel(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'my_model' 
    ....
```

Note, in our case not all of the tables follow the soft delete pattern (we don't care about the history of every single table). Here, you could implement a separate BaseModel that uses the default query class.

```py
class ImmutableBaseModel(Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    query_class = CustomQuery
    ...

class MutableBaseModel(Model):
    __abstract__ = True
```

If you find yourself here and you've not read it yet check out this excellent blog post from Miguel Grinberg on implementing the [soft delete pattern](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/implementing-the-soft-delete-pattern-with-flask-and-sqlalchemy) and [accompanying repo](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/sqlalchemy-soft-delete)

Comment: Though I appreciate a lot Miguel Grinberg's job in tutorials and his advice, I think that blog entry is not a good example. It is a bit old, and also is quite hacky. I believe in 2021 the correct way to do it, and also compatible with SQLAlchemy 2.0, is described in the very SQLAlchemy docs https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/_modules/examples/extending_query/filter_public.html It is way cleaner than what is shown by Miguel in his blog, and is also recommended by SQLAlchemy devs.

Comment: Thanks, Jose, good to know hadn't seen that section in the docs I'll check it out.